# error in hive-hbase integration

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am using hive version 0.12.0 , hadoop version 2.4.0 and hbase version 0.98.3

I created a table info in hbase, populated it with one row of data, gave hive its access (using external table)

when running the query

```
  select count (*) from info;
```

I get

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
 set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_1405407486295_0003, Tracking URL = http://prashasti-Vostro-2520:8088    /proxy/application_1405407486295_0003/
Kill Command = /home/prashasti/Installed/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill     job_1405407486295_0003
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2014-07-15 12:55:14,643 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-07-15 12:55:39,914 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_1405407486295_0003 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_1405407486295_0003_m_000000 (and more) from job    job_1405407486295_0003

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_1405407486295_0003_m_000000

URL:
  http://0.0.0.0:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1405407486295_0003&      tipid=task_1405407486295_0003_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at      org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReaderImpl.close(TableRecordReaderImpl.java:161)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableRecordReader.close(TableRecordReader.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableInputFormat$1.close(HiveHBaseTableInputFormat.java:198)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doClose(HiveRecordReader.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.close(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:96)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.close(MapTask.java:209)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:1950)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:445)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

I already tried the following
1) I made a directory hive/auxlib and added protobuf-*.jar, zookeeper-*.jar , hbase-client-*.jar, hbase-server-*.jar , hbase-common-*.jar , hbase-protobuf-*.jar, hive-hbase-handler-*.jar ,guava-*.jar  from hbase/lib

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4520